# get current time in seconds based on the region in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code but its not showing the current time in seconds like 1h1m1s=3661 .How do I get the following answer in html ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Example</title>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write ('Current time is:',  new Date().now() );



</script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.write is bad way

Comment: ` new Date().now() ` shows the number of seconds since mindnight, 1 Jan 1970

Comment: I am still a beginner in html/javascript I need to just get current time .How do I do that?

Comment: but thats not helping .What do I do with new Date().now()  .I tried that now how do I convert to current time like 1h 1m 1s?

Comment: @RickHoving: Actually, it's number of *milliseconds* since 1/1/1970

Comment: @jason: See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It explains all about the `Date` object and how to use it.

Comment: do you want display time or just milliseconds

Comment: why -1 on the post .I am looking for answer where I am supposed to get the current time of a region and turn that into seconds .

Comment: @susheel Hello Susheel in seconds ,Bt how do I know which region the user is from and get that timezone and convert that time to second?

Comment: you want the region name, timezone..conversion is not needed it takes your computer time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the number of seconds since midnight:

```
(function (D, M, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var display, then, now;
    now = new Date();
    then = new Date();
    then.setHours(0);
    then.setMinutes(0);
    then.setSeconds(0);
    then.setMilliseconds(0);
    display = D.createElement('p');
    display.innerText = 'The time is: ' + 
        M.round(((now.getTime() - then.getTime()) / 1000));
    D.body.appendChild(display);
}(document, Math));
```

Comment: I think the downvotes relate to the question being a pretty straightforward one. The thing is... JavaScript's date manipulation API is a bit demanding, so that you need to roll lots of stuff on your own. I actually prefer @jzworkman's answer to my own, as it's a bit more efficient and considerably more compact.

Comment: @jameslafferty you do we used the 3rd parameter as undefined. I see it in many places. whats the use ??

Comment: @susheel Basically, one of the stupid things that JavaScript does is to allow ```undefined``` to be defined, if some meanie decides to do ```undefined = 'Ha ha';``` for example. Putting it there as a parameter, but not passing anything in protects our execution context from that kind of shenanigans.

Answer (score 5):

```
var d = new Date();
var seconds = d.getHours()*3600 + d.getMinutes()*60 + d.getSeconds();
```

This will give you the total seconds of the current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

will give you seconds since 1 Jan 1970 @ midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(), s = d.getSeconds() + d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getHours() * 3600;
```

The number of seconds since the last midnight, which I believe is what you're looking for.

edit: Note that because JavaScript is executed in the browser, it gets the time from the user's operating system, meaning that it will be correct according to their region and timezone as long as their computer's clock is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours(), min = now.getMinutes(), 
    sec = now.getSeconds(), milli = now.getMilliseconds();
```

And btw, getting milliseconds past midnight is

```
Date.now()
```

Note the lack of parens after Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
parseInt((new Date).getTime() / 1000) % 86400;   //works in all browsers
parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) % 86400;    //as a part of ECMAScript 5 works in newer browsers
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) you can read more about `Date.now()` method

**Edit**

I have to say that this approach only works correctly with UTC +0000, so please consider other answers if this doesn't fit your needs

Comment: This would return the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970(as that is what `GetTime()` returns), not the current day.